# Kerbal Space Program Science Malfunctioning

Tags: kerbal-space-program

I have a major issue here. I can control my Kerbals just fine and even right click to see their propellant reserves, but the options for samples, reports, etc. are *gone*. I can't run experiments from inside the ship either. I was able to do this a day ago, but for some reason, now I can't.

Here is some more info information:

- Windows 7, KSP 1.2.2.xxx
- I use a lot of mods (All load with no errors)
- The problem also exists across all ships and in newly-created saves
- Restarting the game (and computer) does not work
- Using regular application vs. 64 bit version does not fix the issue

Any ideas?

Comment: Sorry about the bad formatting on the information list.

Comment: When you "use a lot of mods" then likely one of them is responsible for the issue. You should post a list of the mods you are using. Maybe someone has experienced this side-effect from one of them. Should nobody be able to help you, you might want to try starting KSP with all mods disabled and see if the problem persists. Then activate them one after another to pinpoint the problematic mod (or combination of mods).

Comment: Do you maybe have any life support / realism mods (homesickness etc) which could make your kerbals "rebel" and refuse to perform advanced work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out :) Turns out, when I was un packing the planetary habitat mod, I left a copy of the parent folder in the game data section and that was confusing the game. Everything works now. Philipp got me on the right track looking back at all the mods! Thanks guys!